# Regex for number range with spaces in digits

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, range

I require regular expression to match for number range. 
E.x.

1. 101-105 (any numbers without space) then i will be creating room 101, 102.. 105
2. 1 0 1 - 1 0 5 (any numbers with single space only) then I will be creating "room 1 0 1", "room 1 0 2",... so on.
3. 15-20 or 1 5-2 0

"-" is used for separating start and end range. 
I want to allow either "no space" or "single space" between the digits.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Regex is a pattern matching language. You can define custom ranges of characters to match. I suggest using [0-9] to match digits. then you can tune the amount of desired occurences using the {min,max} quantifiers.
For example [1-9][0-9]{0,2} would match things like 1, 10 and 109

Comment: specify what output you want on an input with example.

Comment: This is a little bit unclear because you haven't specified if you want the range with dash to be matched, or just numbers.

Comment: It would be far less of a headache if you just used capture groups to to match the numbers (strip the spaces) and test the ranges properly as parsed integers.  What if for example: the number on the right is less than the number on the left - is that still valid?

Comment: it is not specifically for mentioned numbers. it can be any numbers. Of course I am checking that first number should be greater than later. form this i will create range .ex. if range is 10-15 i will be creating 10, 11.. upto 15. Here the thing is user may enter range in 1 0-1 5 . I want to allow only one white space.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match both of your inputs:

```
^1 ?0 ?[1-5]$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vO8uB0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your regexes must be,

1. `^10[1-5]$`
2. `^1 0 [1-5]$`

If you want  both then `OR` the both regexes,

```
^10[1-5]$|^1 0 [1-5]$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yZ1lJ2/1)

Comment: Though you can shorten / optimize it with `^1(?:0| 0 )[1-5]$`

Comment: That's a different expression though. It matches spaces as optional whitespace, the one I mentioned matches them as alternative whitespace allocation - none or all. While the other is likely useful, for this specific scenario it would be practical to take the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b1\s?0\s?[1-5]\b
```

should do it